# Type Armenian in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC

Tags: pdf, adobe

I have a fillable PDF document where i need to type a few words in my native language Armenian. Currently i am using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.

My OS is Windows 7.

Any advise is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether the font used for the field does support characters specific for the Armenian language. If it does, you should be able to enter them. If not, you can't, because you can not change the font of a text field using Reader.

So, in order to change the font, you would need a PDF editing tool, preferably Acrobat (Standard or Pro), and you will also need a font supporting Armenian which allows to be fully embedded.

Comment: Seems like the font of the field does not support armenian characters, as i tried typing Armenian then pasting in the field, but it displays round icons instead of letters. Can you point me to some resources to show me how to install a new font to Adobe Reader?

Comment: You can't install a new font to Adobe Reader (well, even if you could, it would not work anyway). You have to change the form, and for that you would need Acrobat, not Reader. If you have Acrobat, get to the Appearances tab of the Field Properties dialog, and select a font which contains the Armenian characters.